# Copy files to Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a VM I want to copy files to, a console app I want to run on the VM. How do I do this as the Remote Desktop won't let me copy files.

Comment: Did you know you actually can ? adjust the rdp config , so it mounts you local drives and that way you can copy them, or you can open up FTP, of mount a VHD as additional disk on which you copy all the files.

Comment: I'm trying to share my local drives but the win 8 remote desktop link provided by the Azure portal doesn't let me. I've tried using the full Remote Desktop app which does give me the option but it doesn't connect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should just be able to copy/paste like normal.  You can check to make sure rdpclip.exe is running on the VM.

If that doesn't work, you can always open your local drive using \\tsclient\c from within the RDP session.  To share your local drive you can save the RDP file from the Management Portal website, then right-click the .rdp file and select Edit.  Then switch to the Local Resources tab and click More under 'Local devices and resources' and check the drives that you want to share.

Comment: Saving the rdp file to my machine and then right click/edit did the job. Cheers.

Comment: Just want to mention that if you are going to use the same RDP settings for all future connections, then after changing the setting as explained above, go back to the General tab and click Save (or Save As).

Answer (score 4):

In my case simple restart of `rdpclip.exe` did the job, so try it.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the simplest and most reliable way is to use an **Azure File Share**.

1. Create a new storage account.
2. Create a File Share in the storage account.
3. Navigate to the File Share.
4. Click "Connect" and paste the commands to the PowerShell console on your client and on your Azure VM. Commands for Linux and MacOS are available as well.
5. Transfer files to and from the File Share.

The process is more or less automatable. I wrote about it on my blog:
https://engineerer.ch/2020/08/16/copy-large-files-to-an-azure-vm/